# How do you extract noisy connected components from an image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, graph-algorithm

I have a number of polygonal regions (red) in an image delineated by line segments (cyan). However the lines are noisy and incomplete, they aren't perfectly straight and the have chunks missing. Is there a way to robustly extract the intended red polygons?

[image]

If the lines were clean and not broken up connected components would solve this nicely. I've experimented with trying to complete the line segments using Hough transform with little success.

EDIT: Another thought I had was to detect the intersection points of the line segments by first taking the medial axis tranform of the cyan pixels then having a sliding window move over the image and finding windows where there are three or more separate red regions which would indicate locations of cyan intersections. But then not sure what next ..

Comment: This is just my initial thought and I'm sure it's not a great solution but if you focus just on the cyan lines, you could try to find if there is a pixel one away that is also cyan. If not, find the nearest pixel and draw a cyan line between the two.

Comment: Did you have a look at [`HoughLinesP()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga8618180a5948286384e3b7ca02f6feeb)?

Answer (score 0):

I know you probably tried this out, but... Did you apply some morphology? maybe some dilations followed by some erosions, maybe at a ratio of 5:2 to preserve and enhance the connections of the components. Did you test using different Structuring Elements?